# Error in FirebaseConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have sucessfully created app on firebase Concole and the added my bundle id . downloaded Plist file added pod Firebase and now i have added         FIRApp.configure() but getting error in console  on compilation
 [image]

[image]

Comment: Which firebase service demo you are creating?

Comment: database read and write with=> pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.0'

Comment: Try to put `pod 'Firebase'` without version. and perform `pod update`.

Comment: getting same error

Comment: Can you post `pod` file text?

Comment: `platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'fireBaseDemo' do

  use_frameworks!
pod 'Firebase'

 

end`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120311/discussion-between-pranay-and-ayaz-ahmad-tarar).

Comment: okay should i send you project?

Comment: is ther any firewall problem ? program didn't ask me to get data from 'com.google.... ' as i saw in blogs post i was following

Comment: Please continue in chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You getting error because of wrong `pod` line.
Try to change you `pod` as below:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

There is no any `pod` available with `pod 'Firebase'`. See [Available Pods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available_pods).

Also you can see [Update your CocoaPods dependencies](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios#update_your_cocoapods_dependencies_numbered) for Upgrade your iOS app from Firebase.com.

I hope its helps you to resolved your problem.

Comment: well i tried with these two but same error

Comment: @AyazAhmadTarar : only accept answer if it's solved your problem.

Comment: solved with new documentation linked in answer

Answer (score 0):

for IOS 9

```
var rootRef = Firebase(url:"https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com")
```

changed to

```
var rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

Google announced a lot of changes in Google I/O
Please read this [firebase updated doc](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios#get_a_database_reference_numbered)